# Программа для трансляции презентации по локальной сети

Tags: сеть, трансляция, презентации, linux

Честно говорю - искал в сети, но ничего близкого по описанию найти не удалось. К тому же правильных ключевых слов, для краткого описания вопроса для поиска, подобрать не удается.

По существу, задача состоит в следующем. Есть некоторая локальная сеть. Есть некий головной компьютер, на котором преподаватель запускает свою презентацию. Каждый компьютер в сети должен иметь возможность подключиться к этому головному компьютеру (типа пассивного терминала), чтобы смотреть ход этой самой презентации, управляемой с головного компьютера.

Возможно, я что-то не так понимаю и существует другой, более удобный способ, но в данном случае технология видится мне именно так. Пытался использовать что-то вроде удаленного доступа к рабочему столу, но это совсем не то - есть ограничения на число подключенных компьютеров, да и выводит оно все, что происходит на экране у оператора.

Как решить этот вопрос как-то даже и не знаю... Проблема в том, что еще и оборудование старое - целероны, ALt-Linux Школьный 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

При наличии выхода во внешнюю сеть, мы у себя часто пользуемся программой [BeemYourScreen](http://www.beamyourscreen.com/), (а иногда GoToMeeting). Можно транслировать экран, независимо от вида и версии ОС.

Если нужно показать слайды, то можно завести на Google Docs учетную запись. Добавить туда показываемый документ и дать каждому, кто должен смотреть его, ссылку на него.

Comment: >> При наличии выхода во внешнюю сеть Выход-то есть, но дохловат.  Я имел ввиду организовать все в рамках одной локалки, не выходя за ее пределы. Но посмотрю указанные программы - может они не только при наличии внешней сети работать позволяют :)

Answer (score 1):

Еще можно установить связку moodle + openmeetings. С помошью нее можно будет показывать не только презентации, но и организовать вебинар.

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал Ваш вариант в учебном классе, т.е. через удаленный рабочий стол ученики были подключены к рабочему столу учителя, но одновременно могут подключиться только около 4 машин. Выход я нашел в том, чтобы к этим  4 машинам подключились другие ученические компьютеры и тогда весь класс видит презентацию.

Comment: Все же через рабочий стол не так удобно... На компьютерах "2-рой очереди" будет высвечиваться не только презентация, но и часть рабочего стола ученического компьютера. Кстати, у у нас ограничение было в 2 компа. Хотя надо будет поглядеть.Тут еще есть вопрос в учениках. Если долго все это готовить - урок пройдет. если дать возможность свободно обозревать чужой компьютер - могут напакостить, когда учитель не видит :)

Answer (score 0):

teamviewer - существуют дистрибутивы для различных ОС

Answer (score 0):

iTalc также подойдет для этих целей

Answer (score 0):

Делается все довольно просто и действительно работает. Сейчас у самого возникла такая необходимость. Дали новое оборудование в начальную школу, комплекты, а на чем построить сеть Вопрос. Делаем вот так качаем Italc, максимум версию 1.0.13, версия 2.0 нехочет почемуто работать с пол пинка. Устанавливаем по этому мануалу.school56orsk.narod.ru/info.files/metod/informat/italc/italc.docи все работает тестирую связка винда7, винда хр, виндовс сервер 2003,пока полет нормальный советую.. Программа здесь: http://sourceforge.net/projects/italc/files/italc/Версия 1.0.9 русифицирована